# Form height in IE10

Tags: css, forms, firefox, internet-explorer-10

I have developed a from with label on left and input box on right. In Chrome and Safari it works fine, but in Firefox and IE10 its height is distracted. Here is a screen shot! [IE10] https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQR73.png

Here is the CSS

```
.comment-form-author label, .comment-form-email label, .comment-form-url label {
  font-size: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 11px 18px 14px 18px;
  color: #868686;
}
.comment-form-author label, .comment-form-email label {
    padding-right: 33px;
}
.comment-form-author label {
    padding-right: 31px;
}
.comment-form-author input[type='text'], .comment-form-email input, .comment-form-url input {
  padding: 18px 18px 15px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  border-left: 0;
  margin-left: -3px;
  width: 270px;
}
.comment-form-author, .comment-form-url {

}
.comment-form-comment textarea {
  height: 55px;
  width: 382px;
  padding: 16px 12px 16px 12px;
}
```

Comment: Try using `box-sizing: border-box` on both labels and input, and set them to the same height. p/s: IE supports this from v8 and above, and remember to use `-moz-` vendor prefix for it to work in Firefox. [Source](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me check it.